# Wrap code with common functionality, while passing down a parameter

Tags: java, wrapper, functional-interface

I have the following code:

```
public void createProject() throws ServiceException {
    Project project = new ProjectMapper().map(pipeline);

    // repeating code
    Connection conn;
    try {
        conn = JDBCConnectionManager.getConnection(POOL_NAME, DB_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        throw new ServiceException(e1);
    }
    try {
    // end repeating code

        ProjectAccess.writeProject(conn, project);

    // repeating code
    } catch (SQLException | JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ServiceException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            releaseConnection(conn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServiceException(e);
        }
    }
    // end repeating code
}
```

Basically I want to get rid of the two try / catch blocks and put them in a wrapper as they are always the same.
I thought about using a functional interface and it almost works, except I have to pass down the `conn` variable into my code, which doesnt work with my solution:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface DatabaseLogic {        
    public void execute() throws SQLException, JsonProcessingException;        
}

public void executeSql(DatabaseLogic dl) throws ServiceException {
    Connection conn;
    try {
        conn = JDBCConnectionManager.getConnection(POOL_NAME, DB_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        throw new ServiceException(e1);
    }
    try {
        dl.execute(conn);
    } catch (SQLException | JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ServiceException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            releaseConnection(conn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServiceException(e);
        }
    }
}


    new DatabaseRunner().executeSql(() -> {
        IDataCursor pipelineCursor = pipeline.getCursor();
        String projectName = IDataUtil.getString(pipelineCursor, "projectName");
        // how can I access the conn object here?
        ProjectAccess.deleteProject(conn, projectName);
    });
```

So, as I wrote in the comment, is there a way to use a functional interface and access a variable from the enclosing method?

Answer (score 1):

Hmpf, of course I figured it out a few minutes later. I just have to add the Connection parameter to the interface:

```
public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException, JsonProcessingException;

new DatabaseRunner().executeSql((conn) -> {
    IDataCursor pipelineCursor = pipeline.getCursor();
    String projectName = IDataUtil.getString(pipelineCursor, "projectName");
    ProjectAccess.deleteProject(conn, projectName);
});
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way ;-)